# Android: webview in software layer mode doesn't work with google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

Android viewview component if set as below:

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

doesn't show google maps correctly. The result look really bad as picture following:

[image]

on the contrary set layer as LAYER_TYPE_NONE (default) the google maps is showed correctly as you can see:

[image]

My problem here is that I need to get a screenshot of the current webview showing maps (using draw() or view cache, is the same) but also if the maps is showed correctly in the screen if I try to get the screenshot I got the bad image result as first picture show. This mean the internal webview code when try to draw map in something different from the screen (like my bitmap for get screenshot through draw() call) switch to software layer mode and draw bad image.

Someone know the reasons of this behaviour or have a suggestion regarding some workaround allowing me to get correct screenshot image of google maps?

Thank you

Comment: why do you need View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE ?

Comment: I don't need it but is just for explain what is happen if I try to get screenshot using draw() call.

Comment: Maybe it's because it does not apply anti-aliasing

Comment: At this point everything can be and I'm not also sure regarding the possibility to get correct screenshot. Anyway I'm open to any solution. What is the way to force apply anti-aliasing as you suggest?
Thank you

Comment: You can call setLayerType passing View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE and a Paint object as the second argument. Paint object with setAntiAlias = true. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html

Comment: I can try but, also in case of working, this will "fix" the map showed inside the webview. On the contrary I need a way to capture the view in my internal bitmap...

Comment: Confirm after tested also this suggestion of add custom paint object doesn't work. Webview component seem really bad!

Comment: Did you ever find a good workaround for this?

Comment: Sorry no, I gave up follow this way since android webview control is really too bad.

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that if you try something like the following, you will get the bad quality image?

```
    View content = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    getScreen(content);

private void getScreen(View content)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
        File file = new File("/sdcard/test.png");
        try 
        {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
            ostream.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. By the way I checked the internat android framework code and I verified the getDrawingCache() function use internally the same draw() function call (this just for a note). In any case the result of get screen image is the bad result you'll see in my first post.